# Build custom driver for linux

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel, driver

I am new to building C lib and have mostly worked with python. My goal is to take the source code from https://github.com/torvalds/linux and build a custom driver for USB/IP (https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/usb/usbip) module (some modification).

I copied only /tool/usbip/ assuming that USB and USB-IP are already present in the alpine.

I have set up a docker Image:

```
FROM alpine

COPY . .

RUN apk add build-base autoconf automake libtool eudev-dev libusb-dev

WORKDIR /tool/usbip/

RUN ./autogen.sh
RUN ./configure
RUN make install
```

I am getting the following error for make install:

```
Step 7/7 : RUN make install
 ---> Running in 48f53c225a99
Making install in libsrc
make[1]: Entering directory '/tool/usbip/libsrc'
  CC       libusbip_la-names.lo
In file included from names.c:23:
usbip_common.h:18:10: fatal error: linux/usb/ch9.h: No such file or directory
   18 | #include <linux/usb/ch9.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:459: libusbip_la-names.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tool/usbip/libsrc'
make: *** [Makefile:500: install-recursive] Error 1
```

This could mean that alpine doesn't have a USB drive. How do I compile and install the driver in that docker?

Another solution can be to build the entire Linux code from the repo, but can  I use alpine and add a USB-IP driver there, as I can see that alpine is very lightweight?

I see some Kconfig and Makefile, but I need guidance on building the required driver, as my task also requires modifying drivers/USB/usbip code and building the driver for usbip.

Some blog links or youtube videos on build drivers will also help, but I was not able to find any good resources online.

---

Updated docker file:

```
FROM alpine:latest

COPY . /linux

RUN apk add build-base autoconf \
    automake libtool eudev-dev \
    linux-headers flex bison gmp-dev \
    mpc1-dev mpfr-dev


WORKDIR /linux

RUN zcat /proc/config.gz > .config
RUN make olddefconfig
RUN make modules_prepare
RUN make M=drivers/usb/usbip modules

WORKDIR /linux/tools/usb/usbip/

RUN ./autogen.sh
RUN ./configure
RUN make install
```

Comment: The header file exists: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/usb/ch9.h. Not sure how we could help you without knowing which library you are building.

Comment: You need to install `linux-headers` at least. You don't need `libusb-dev`. `tools/usb/usbip`is not a driver, it is a userspace utility. The driver is in `drivers/usb/usbip` Do you want to modify and compile both?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I am building usbip (https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/usb/usbip) Lib usage given here: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/tools/usb/usbip

Comment: @dimich Yes, I need to modify the tool and driver. I was just starting with testing the tool. I added linux-header in alpine and now my docker is able to build tool. But I am still not able to build the usbip driver, this is the last part of the puzzle I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Download kernel sources and go to its root.
- Copy `.config` for system you want to build for. E.g. if it is your running system and it provides `/proc/config.gz` then `zcat /proc/config.gz > .config`
- `make olddefconfig`
- Ensure `CONFIG_USBIP` and other modules are enabled as a modules:

```
$ grep CONFIG_USBIP .config
CONFIG_USBIP_CORE=m
CONFIG_USBIP_VHCI_HCD=m
CONFIG_USBIP_VHCI_HC_PORTS=8
CONFIG_USBIP_VHCI_NR_HCS=1
CONFIG_USBIP_HOST=m
# CONFIG_USBIP_DEBUG is not set
```

If not, run `make nconfig` (or make `menuconfig`), navigate to `Device Drivers`->`USB support`->`USB/IP support` and enable it as a module (`<M>`); save configuration.

- `make modules_prepare`
- `make M=drivers/usb/usbip modules`

Your modules are in `drivers/usb/usbip/`

Comment: It is working, thanks. I know this is not related to this but when I run: usbip list
I am getting the error usbip: error: failed to open /usr/share/hwdata//usb.ids, does this means I need to enable some other driver or something?

Comment: @ooo `/usr/share/hwdata/usb.ids` is provided by `hwdata` package. Install this package.